# Angular routing automatically redirects to default path

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

This is my routing config

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '', redirectTo: 'signIn', pathMatch: 'full'
}, {
  path: 'signIn', loadChildren: './sign-in/sign-in.module#SignInModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard]
}, {
  path: 'signUp', canActivate: [AuthGuard], loadChildren: './sign-up/sign-up.module#SignUpModule'
}, {
  path: 'home', canActivate: [AuthGuard], loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule'
}];
```

And my auth guard is

```
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
      return this.webService.getUser().pipe( map(data => {
        if (data['status'] === 1 && data['user'] && !data['role']) {
          if (state.url === '/signIn' || state.url === '/signUp') {
            console.log('home');
            this.router.navigate(['home']);
          } else {
            console.log('true');
            return true;
          }
        } else {
          sessionStorage.clear();
          if (state.url !== '/signIn' && state.url !== '/signUp') {
            this.router.navigate(['signIn']);
          } else {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }));
  }
```

It loads every path with 'signIn' like when ever I want to visit 'home' it goes to `http://localhost:4200/home/signIn` and loads 'singIn' page but if I remove empty path it loads 'home' page correctly. What is the best way to load home page only? I don't want to add 'signIn' to every page. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you please add AuthGuard ts file in question

Comment: I added my auth guard

Comment: Let me check what happened here and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

You are routing to a relative path. 'home'. Meaning whatever is in your route at the time of routing, will stay there.

You can route to an absolute path by adding a slash ('/') before the route.

```
this.router.navigate(['/home']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use all route in the main route (empty once) and use the others in "children" of that route, in this way you can use one-time guard for all in "canActivateChild"
Your main empty route no need to guard you direct this route to your main page component and other guards automatically redirect the user to "sign in" page.

[CanActivateChild guild and example](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivateChild)

Comment: Setting an AuthGuard interface on pages such as 'register', 'login', 'unauthorized', '404', etc hardly seems useful. OP's problem can easily be solved without making decisions like this.

Comment: @Carsten ok, well, but using empty as a default "redirect" is not usual, and this type is better for organized routes to continue a growing project.